# can't refresh data with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

My data are defined in a global variable `ArrayList cells` and my custom `ArrayAdapter` holds a reference to that variable:

```
class CellAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cell> {

        CellAdapter() {
            super(context, 0, 0, cells);
        }
}
```

Then I have a method in which i refresh the cells by calling `clear()` and then using the `add()` method. After doing this, then I call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The adapter should still hold a reference to the global variable with which I have initialized it, right? Anyway, it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is cells declared and initialized?

Comment: no cells is an ArrayList like I have said. it's declared as a global variable and initialized in the onCreate of the activity holding the ListView

Comment: Can you post your getView method?

Answer (score 1):

`adapter.clear()` is calling `cells.clear()` since the super class holds a reference to your `ArrayList<Cell>`. He works, but you are filling up the adapter with an empty dataset.

Comment: I have tried to remove adapter.clear() and adpater.addAll(), and with the debugger I see that the adapter has all the data. Maybe notifyDataSetChanged() isn't doing anything?

Comment: if the dataset is not changed probably, i am not sure about that, getView could not be called

Answer (score 0):

An `ArrayAdapter` does not make a copy of your `cells` array list. Whenever you make modifications to the objects inside the `cells` array, you can just call `notifyDataSetChanged` on it.

If you modify the list itself (especially removing items from the list) you must notify the adapter, otherwise it will start throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
adapter.clear();
```

is clearing your cells object as well.

Just don't call clear and addAll

If you have updated your cells list then just call:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

It will refresh